# One cell is contained in another cell in R

Tags: r, compare, grepl

I have something like that:

```
One       Two 
A,B,C       A 
A,C,        Z 
R,F,        K 
T           T
```

And I would like to get in the 'Third' yes/no if 'Two' is contained in 'One'.

```
One       Two    Three
A,B,C       A     yes
A,C,        Z     no 
R,F,        K     no 
T           T     yes
```

I know I can get it by using `grepl`, like that: 
`grepl("A" , all$One) -> all&Three`. But I have a few hundreds cases, so I am not able to write all those individual queries.
So how I should implement the whole 'Two' cell as a pattern in a `grepl`function?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `all$Three <- mapply(grepl, all$Two, all$One)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapply()`:

```
all <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"One       Two 
A,B,C       A 
A,C,        Z 
R,F,        K 
T           T")
all$Three <- mapply(grepl, all$Two, all$One)
all
# > all
#     One Two Three
# 1 A,B,C   A  TRUE
# 2  A,C,   Z FALSE
# 3  R,F,   K FALSE
# 4     T   T  TRUE
```

If you really want "yes" or "no" as result, then you can do:

```
all$Three <- ifelse(mapply(grepl, all$Two, all$One), "yes", "no")
```

or (as commented by Rui Barradas, thx):

```
all$Three <- factor(mapply(grepl, all$Two, all$One), labels = c("no", "yes"))
```

Comment: If you want to match the OP's output, why not `factor(mapply(etc), labels = c("no", "yes"))`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(Three = str_detect(One, Two))
#    One Two Three
#1 A,B,C   A  TRUE
#2  A,C,   Z FALSE
#3  R,F,   K FALSE
#4     T   T  TRUE
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text  =
    "One       Two
A,B,C       A
A,C,        Z
R,F,        K
T           T", header = T)
```